# how to make Ui admin form field disable dynamically

Tags: magento2.3, uicomponent, adminform

I have `ui componenet` form i want to disable one field dynamically when add only.

```
 <field formElement="select" name="classification" sortOrder="40">
        <settings>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Classification</label>
            <disabled>true</disabled>
            <dataScope>classification</dataScope>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options class="Vendor\Module\Model\Object\Source\DivisionAgeFrontEndClass"/>
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

`<disabled>true</disabled>` this line disable for all action.
i have refer [this](https://webkul.com/blog/disable-attribute-in-product-edit-admin-panel-in-magento-2/) link but not getting idea how to use this

Here is `Dataprovider.php` code

```
public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $model) {
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
        }
        $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('pacreg_team');

        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
            $model->setData($data);
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('pacreg_team');
        }

        return $this->loadedData;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataProvider.php`

```
public function getData()
{
    if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
    $items = $this->collection->getItems();
    foreach ($items as $model) {
        $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
        if ($model->getId()) {
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()]['do_we_hide_it'] = true;
        } else {
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()]['do_we_hide_it'] = false;
        }
    }
    $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('pacreg_team');

    if (!empty($data)) {
        $model = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
        $model->setData($data);
        $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
        $this->dataPersistor->clear('pacreg_team');
    }

    return $this->loadedData;
}
```

in your form ui component

```
<field formElement="select" name="classification" sortOrder="40">
        <settings>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Classification</label>
            <dataScope>classification</dataScope>
            <imports>
                <link name="disabled">${ $.provider}:data.do_we_hide_it</link>
            </imports>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options class="Vendor\Module\Model\Object\Source\DivisionAgeFrontEndClass"/>
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override getMeta() function in your DataProvider class

```
public function getMeta()
{
$meta = parent::getMeta();
$id = $this->request->getParam('entity_id');
if(isset($id)){

$meta['fieldset_name']['children']['field_name']['arguments']['data']['config']['visible'] = 1;
}
else{
$meta['fieldset_name']['children']['field_name']['arguments']['data']['config']['visible'] = 0; 
}
return $meta;
}
```

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: I am getting an empty array on printing `$meta`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below import syntax to dynamically disable the fields

```xml
<field formElement="select" name="classification" sortOrder="40">
    <settings>
        <dataType>text</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Classification</label>
        <disabled>true</disabled>
        <dataScope>classification</dataScope>
        <!-- start import check the condition -->
        <imports> 
            <link name="disabled">${ $.provider }:data.general.disable_classification</link>
        </imports>
        <!-- end import check the condition -->
        <validation>
            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
        </validation>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <select>
            <settings>
                <options class="Vendor\Module\Model\Object\Source\DivisionAgeFrontEndClass"/>
            </settings>
        </select>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

in your `dataprovider` class file in the `getData()` function you can add value off `data.general.disable_classification` so based on that field will be disabled.

you can refer this snippet before returning the data

```php
$classification = $data['items'][0]['classification'];
$generalData = $data['items'][0];
$generalData['disable_classification'] = !empty($generalData['classification']);  // add your boolean condition to disable element
$newData[$classification] = [
    'general' => $generalData,
];
$return $newData;
```

let me know based on this is the way you dynamically want to disable it. If you want to disable it based on the other form element. I'll update the answer

Comment: I have updated dataprovider code.Can you please guide me how to use your code in my function with new action only.

Comment: I think you already got the same answer and it working now